# difficult time emulating bootstrap @media query behaviors

Tags: css

I am using `bootstrap` in an application, and I love it. I'm very fond of the CSS `@media` queries for handling different sized screens.

I have a few situations where I need to write my own classes that use the same queries. For example, I have a `navbar` on my application; and I want to increase the font size and zoom for the user if they are on a smaller screen.

I tried just mirroring the way those queries were laid out, but I cannot seem to replicate the behavior.

### html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <!-- css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="skin.css"/>
</head>
<body class="zoom-xs-150 zoom-sm-120">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top ">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- navbar content -->
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

and then my CSS looks like this;

### CSS

```
@media (max-device-width: 1200px) {
  // zoom-lg styles
}
@media (max-device-width: 992px) {
  // zoom-md styles
}
@media (max-device-width: 768px) {
  // zoom-sm styles
}
@media (max-device-width: 360px) {
 // zoom-xs styles
}
```

but despite it all, I simply cannot seem to convince it to work. I have tried fiddling around with all of the properties (like using `min-width`, or not using `device-width`, etc) and the results are inconsistent and I am having a hard time understanding why.

Is there something special to using them that I am missing?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with your `zoom-...` classes? I would read it as "font-size 150% on xs devices and 120% on sm devices". Am I correct?
What exactly is not working? What is the expected output/behaviour and what is it actually doing?

Comment: Try using `@media (max-width: 1200px) { *css here* }`

Comment: Yes. I want to apply a specific `zoom` on small and extra small devices.

Comment: I'll give `max-width` a try again. It didn't work before, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: A media-query using *max-device-width* checks for the whole screen no matter what the actual browser-size is, but using *max-width* considers the size of the viewport (e.g. remaining browser-window-size after toolbars, device-bars, ...).

Comment: Well, I'm confused about what I need then. For example, my Nexus 6 has a very high resolution, but it's a small screen. I want it to use the `sm` or `xs` styles, despite its resolution. There is no way the queries can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CSS:**

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .zoom-sm-120 nav {
        font-size: 120%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 360px) {
    .zoom-xs-150 nav {
        font-size: 150%;
    }
}
```

A jsFiddle with a more colorful stylesheet, for better understanding: http://jsfiddle.net/DrSRT/639/